# Как в Rust посчитать количество уникальных символов?

Tags: текст, rust

Накидал небольшой код, на основе того, что нашел в сети, но пока не могу понять как применить это ко всем строкам (выдает только значение 1й)

**Задача**: вывести длину строки и количество уникальных символов для каждой из строк `stdin`

```
use std::io;

/// Retrun unique characters count of a string.
fn uniq_chars_count(string: &str) -> usize {
    let string_vector: Vec<char> = string.chars().collect();
    let mut y = string_vector.clone();

    y.dedup();
    y.len()
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut input = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input)?;

    let u_chars = uniq_chars_count(input.trim());

    println!("Unique char lenght: {}", u_chars );
    println!("Line length: {}", input.trim().len());
}
```

Comment: На всякий случай отмечу что Rust'овые char'ы это именно codepoint'ы - не факт что под "символами" пользователь понимает именно их. Например, в строчке "é" два char'а - http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b170b5ef70895dda05703216ed597132 Если это может быть важно для задачи, то советую статью https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/14/stop-ascribing-meaning-to-unicode-code-points/ + работать с графемныи кластерами char'ов через пакет https://unicode-rs.github.io/unicode-segmentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут несколько проблем.

Во-первых, метод среза строки [`len()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.len) возвращает количество байт в строке, что не всегда соответствует количеству символов. Стороки в Rust хранятся в кодировке UTF-8 и длина одного символа может быть от одного до четырех байт.

В данном случае общее количество символов можно получить из вектора `string_vector` до вызова `dedup()`.

Во-вторых, метод [`dedup()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.dedup) удаляет повторяющиеся **последовательные** элементы вектора. Т.е. чтобы остались только уникальные элементы вектор нужно предварительно отсортировать.

Еще, чтобы Rust не ругался на несоответствие типов в конце функции `main()` нужно вернуть `Result`.

Или можно указать, что `main()` ничего не возвращает:

```
 fn main(){
    ...
 }
```

и вместо `?` использовать [`unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) или [`expect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect).

Вот рабочий код с циклом по строкам из `stdin`:

```
use std::io;

/// Retrun tuple with total and unique characters count of a string.
fn uniq_chars_count(string: &str) -> (usize, usize) {
    let mut string_vector: Vec<char> = string.chars().collect();
    let t_chars = string_vector.len();
    string_vector.sort();
    string_vector.dedup();
    (t_chars, string_vector.len())
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut input = String::new();
    while io::stdin.read_line(&mut input)? != 0 {
        let (t_chars, u_chars) = uniq_chars_count(input.trim());
        println!("Unique char lenght: {}", u_chars );
        println!("Line length: {}", t_chars);
        input.clear();
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

[playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=61e90e4495ba8d8968f01149576fdf60&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Для решения этой задачи так же можно использовать коллекции, которые хранят только уникальные элементы [HashSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) и [BTreeSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html):

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

/// Retrun tuple with total and unique characters count of a string.
fn uniq_chars_count(string: &str) -> (usize, usize) {
    let mut t_chars = 0;
    let u_chars = string.chars().inspect(|_| t_chars+=1).collect::<HashSet<char>>().len();
    (t_chars, u_chars)
}
```

В целях обучения советую порешать задачки на сайте https://exercism.io . Там после публикации своего ответа можно посмотреть решения других участников.

Comment: Как быть если я хочу использовать `for line in stdin.lock().lines()` читать входящий поток, а не только одну строку?

Comment: Добавил цикл в пример